# Jenkins File Exists Conditional Step - Variable Usage?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have the following 'File Exists' conditional step in a Jenkins project. I know the 'File' field is searching for a file pattern, but I want to know if I can use a parameter variable in the field as in the image.

[image]

When I try what's pictured, I get an 'Unrecognized macro' error. I've also tried ${FileManifest} with the same result.